# Error in lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) : illegal input detected before taking any integration steps

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate and optimize parameters with time dependent transmission rates in the infectious disease dynamics model. Since the incidence data is periodic, assume betaH=aH*(1+bH*cos(2*pi*t/12)) according to the literature. But under real data simulation, I get the error: illegal input detected before taking any integration steps.
I'm not very familiar with differential equation solving, so please tell me, how it should be modified.

```
library(deSolve)

# SEIARWF differential equation
SEIARWF <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dS=0.001048*N+0.00595*R-(aH*(1+bH*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*(I+A)/N-
                            (aW*(1+bW*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*W/N-
                            (aF*(1+bF*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*FD/N-0.000582*S
    dE=(aH*(1+bH*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*(I+A)/N+
       (aW*(1+bW*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*W/N+
       (aF*(1+bF*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*FD/N-
       0.75*E-0.000582*E
    dI=0.1*0.75*E-1*I-0.000582*I
    dA=0.9*0.75*E-1*A-0.000582*A
    dR=1*I+1*A-0.00595*R-0.000582*R
    dW=3014000000000*I+1507000000000*A-1.3333*W
    dFD=3014000000000*I+1507000000000*A-1.3333*FD
    N=S+E+I+A+R
    
    list(c(dS, dE, dI, dA, dR, dW, dFD, N)) 
  })
}

# state
N0 <- 1292270000                   
Infected <- c(1429,1813,2227,1752,1541,1467,1249,1188,1022,973,1052,731,1539,1604,
              2190,1838,1327,1183,1038,1052,942,997,1045,786,1704,2219,2768,2116,
              1818,1490,1228,1207,1042,1179,1213,1023,2183,2039,2616,2176,1842,1643,
              1571,1612,1334,1306,1292,963,1843,1871,2726,2112,1786,1425,1305,1226,
              1061,1096,1097,977,1930,2444,2730,2048,1735,1487,1338,1424,1157,1195,
              1237,1550,2288,2304,3076,2567,2180,1719,1584,1461,1421,1468,1684,1930,
              2342,2930,4178,3270,2459,2118,2010,2116,1871,1872,2062,1974,2338,3180,
              3557,2662,2354,1889,1843,1906,1737,1763,1959,2083,3076,3145,3628,2772,
              2241,1794,1874,1899,1723,1764,1960,2026,2655,3018,3140,2510,2052,1836,
              1958,2054,1908,1849,1883,2125,2893,2301,3032,2668,2165,1956,1991,1931,
              1792,1982,2131,2327,2497,2468,3318,2676,2410,2143,2094,2105,1966,1885,
              2065,2295,2306,2752,3141,2568,2559,2397,2390,2439,2049,2006,2191,2216,
              2811,2441,3163,2651,2489,2160,2324,2249,1928,1863,2304,2220)
I0 <- Infected[1]                  
A0 <- Infected[1]*9                
E0 <- 19054                        
R0 <- 303166542                   
S0 = N0 - E0 - I0 - A0 - R0        
W0 <- 5169000000000000             
FD0 <- 11080000000000000           
initials <- c(S = S0, E = E0, I = I0, A =A0, R = R0, N = N0, W = W0, FD = FD0)  

# time
t <- 0:(length(Infected)-1)

# RSS optim
RSS <- function(parameters) { 
  names(parameters) <- c("aH", "bH", "aW", "bW", "aF", "bF")
  out <- ode(y = initials, times = t, func = SEIARWF, parms = parameters)
  fit <- out[ , 4]
  sum((Infected - fit)^2)
}

Opt <- optim(par=c(0.0005, 0.5, 0.0102, 0.5, 0.0429, 0.5), 
             fn = RSS, method = "L-BFGS-B",
             lower = c(0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1), 
             upper = c(Inf, 1, Inf, 1, Inf, 1),
             control = list(), hessian = TRUE)
Opt
Opt_par <- setNames(Opt$par, c("aH", "bH", "aW", "bW", "aF", "bF"))
Opt_par
```

Comment: To debug your code, first run the model separately with `ode` alone and without an optimizer.  If this does not help, start with a simpler model to improve understanding of differential equation modelling. One of the most obvious problems in this code is the scale: W0 and FD0 are bigger than 10^15 or even 10^16 while the data are given in thousands. Here it helps to adapt the tolerances of the solver or (easier) to rescale the problem, so that data and state variables are within reasonable limits. As a rule of thumb, rescale it to a range to about 10^-3 ... 10^3.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As you can see, the model is based on the most basic infectious disease dynamics model, SEIR, with the added variables W and FD referring to different modes of transmission: contaminated water and food (in addition to person-to-person infection). Based on the literature, the state variables W and FD (the amount of virus in contaminated water and food) were estimated. @tpetzoldt

Comment: Similar to the equation in this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8240442/, but I assume that the viruses in W and FD originate only from the emissions of infected people after starting the simulation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I will keep learning about this.

Answer (score 0):

The model has several issues, so the question cannot be solved. There are however some obvious mistakes. Solving them may help for a next iteration:

1. The order of derivatives in the `initials` mus exactly match the order in the list returned by the model, see documentation of package **lsoda**.
2. `N` is obviously the total number, not a derivative. Therefore, it has no initial value and needs to be returned as second argument from the model, i.e. after the parentheses of the states vector (see documentation). Finally, it needs to be calculated before the state equations.
3. To develop a model, always start with a simple version and then build the model up step by step. Run the model without an optimizer first and test the optimizer with a simpler example. Put the pieces together after all building blocks work.
4. The scales of the state variables are very different and especially `dW` and `dFD` are very big. In such a case it is necessary to adapt the integration tolerances or, much easier, to rescale variables. However, I assume that the inconsistencies result from an error of units.
5. The aim of parts of the model remain unclear. What are the state variables `W` and `FD`? Where was the model taken from? Please add some explanation how the model is motivated.

The following model corrects issues (1) and (2) and shows how to test the model before putting it into the optimizer.

```r
library("deSolve")

# SEIARWF differential equation
SEIARWF <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  # cat(state, "\n") # enable this for debugging
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    N <- S + E + I + A + R
    
    dS <- 0.001048*N+0.00595*R-(aH*(1+bH*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*(I+A)/N-
      (aW*(1+bW*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*W/N-
      (aF*(1+bF*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*FD/N-0.000582*S
    dE <- (aH*(1+bH*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*(I+A)/N+
      (aW*(1+bW*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*W/N+
      (aF*(1+bF*cos(2*pi*t/12)))*S*FD/N-
      0.75*E-0.000582*E
    dI <- 0.1*0.75*E-1*I-0.000582*I
    dA <- 0.9*0.75*E-1*A-0.000582*A
    dR <- 1*I+1*A-0.00595*R-0.000582*R
    dW <- 3014000000000 * I + 1507000000000 * A - 1.3333 * W
    dFD <- 3014000000000 * I + 1507000000000 * A - 1.3333 * FD

    list(c(dS, dE, dI, dA, dR, dW, dFD), N = N) 
  })
}

# Infected <- .... # omitted for now, can be re-introduced after correcting the model

# states
# N0 <- 1292270000 # not needed, as N is calculated as sum of all states
I0 <- 1429 # Infected[1]                  
A0 <- I0 * 9                
E0 <- 19054                        
R0 <- 303166542                   
S0 <- N0 - E0 - I0 - A0 - R0        
W0 <- 5169000000000000
FD0 <- 11080000000000000
initials <- c(S = S0, E = E0, I = I0, A =A0, R = R0, W = W0, FD = FD0)  

parameters <- c(aH = 0.0005, bH = 0.5, aW = 0.0102, bW = 0.5, aF = 0.0429, bF = 0.5)

# time
#t <- 0:(length(Infected)-1)
t <- 0:180 # the length of Infected

SEIARWF(1, initials, parameters)

# The scales of the states are very different, 
# so we need individual tolerances for the different states.
out <- ode(y = initials, times = t, func = SEIARWF, parms = parameters, atol = c(1e6, rep(1e-6, 4), rep(1e6, 2)))

plot(out)
```

The plot shows that it does not solve the scaling issue (wrong measurement units), but may help to improve the model formulation. I think that it can help to think about meaning and scales of `W` and `FD`.

I would recommend to read more about the scientific background and the formulation of exponential growth. It may be found in an a good microbiology or epidemiology texbook or about ecological modelling, for example, in https://hankstevens.github.io/Primer-of-Ecology/expo.html